# how to use threads to grab multiple chunks of a file concurrently from server but write to disk atomically?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, locking, python-requests

I am stuck in a grieve problem, and not able to figure out which way to go, in attempts made whole day I have posted so many times, this is not a duplicate question, since I need clarity how can I use multiple threads to grab a multiple chunks simultaneously from a server but write to disk atomically by locking the file write operation for single thread access; while the next thread waits for lock to get released.

```
import argparse,logging, Queue, os, requests, signal, sys, time, threading
import utils as _fdUtils

DESKTOP_PATH = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")

appName = 'FileDownloader'

logFile = os.path.join(DESKTOP_PATH, '%s.log' % appName)

_log = _fdUtils.fdLogger(appName, logFile, logging.DEBUG, logging.DEBUG, console_level=logging.DEBUG)

queue = Queue.Queue()
STOP_REQUEST = threading.Event()
maxSplits = threading.BoundedSemaphore(3)
threadLimiter = threading.BoundedSemaphore(5)
lock = threading.Lock()
```

**Update:1**

```
def _grabAndWriteToDisk(url, saveTo, first=None, queue=None, mode='wb', irange=None):
    """ Function to download file..

        Args:
            url(str): url of file to download
            saveTo(str): path where to save file
            first(int): starting byte of the range
            queue(Queue.Queue): queue object to set status for file download
            mode(str): mode of file to be downloaded
            irange(str): range of byte to download

    """
    fileName = url.split('/')[-1]
    filePath = os.path.join(saveTo, fileName)
    fileSize = int(_fdUtils.getUrlSizeInBytes(url))
    downloadedFileSize = 0 if not first else first
    block_sz = 8192
    irange = irange if irange else '0-%s' % fileSize
    # print mode
    resp = requests.get(url,  headers={'Range': 'bytes=%s' % irange}, stream=True)

    fileBuffer = resp.raw.read()
    with open(filePath, mode) as fd:
        downloadedFileSize += len(fileBuffer)
        fd.write(fileBuffer)
        status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (downloadedFileSize, downloadedFileSize * 100. / fileSize)
        status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
        sys.stdout.write('%s\r' % status)
        time.sleep(.05)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if downloadedFileSize == fileSize:
            STOP_REQUEST.set()
            if queue:
                queue.task_done()
            _log.info("Download Completed %s%% for file %s, saved to %s",
                downloadedFileSize * 100. / fileSize, fileName, saveTo)


class ThreadedFetch(threading.Thread):
    """ docstring for ThreadedFetch
    """
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super(ThreadedFetch, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def run(self):
        threadLimiter.acquire()
        try:
            items = self.queue.get()
            url = items[0]
            saveTo = DESKTOP_PATH if not items[1] else items[1]
            split = items[-1]

            # grab split chunks in separate thread.
            if split > 1:
                maxSplits.acquire()
                try:
                    sizeInBytes = int(_fdUtils.getUrlSizeInBytes(url))
                    byteRanges = _fdUtils.getRange(sizeInBytes, split)
                    mode = 'wb'
                    th = threading.Thread(target=_grabAndWriteToDisk, args=(url, saveTo, first, self.queue, mode, _range))
                    _log.info("Pulling for range %s using %s" , _range, th.getName())
                    th.start()
                    # _grabAndWriteToDisk(url, saveTo, first, self.queue, mode, _range)
                    mode = 'a'
                finally:
                    maxSplits.release()

            else:
                while not STOP_REQUEST.isSet():
                    self.setName("primary_%s" % url.split('/')[-1])
                    # if downlaod whole file in single chunk no need
                    # to start a new thread, so directly download here.
                    _grabAndWriteToDisk(url, saveTo, 0, self.queue)
        finally:
            threadLimiter.release()


def main(appName, flag='with'):

    args = _fdUtils.getParser()
    urls_saveTo = {}

    if flag == 'with':
        _fdUtils.Watcher()
    elif flag != 'without':
        _log.info('unrecognized flag: %s', flag)
        sys.exit()

    # spawn a pool of threads, and pass them queue instance
    # each url will be downloaded concurrently
    for i in xrange(len(args.urls)):
        t = ThreadedFetch(queue)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    split = 4
    try:
        for url in args.urls:
            # TODO: put split as value of url as tuple with saveTo
            urls_saveTo[url] = args.saveTo

        # populate queue with data 
        for url, saveTo in urls_saveTo.iteritems():
            queue.put((url, saveTo, split))

        # wait on the queue until everything has been processed
        queue.join()
        _log.info('Finsihed all dowonloads.')
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        _log.critical('! Received keyboard interrupt, quitting threads.')
```

I expect to multiple threads grab each chunk but in the terminal i see same thread grabbing each range of chunk:

> INFO - Pulling for range 0-25583 using Thread-1
>
> INFO - Pulling for range 25584-51166 using Thread-1
>
> INFO - Pulling for range 51167-76748 using Thread-1
>
> INFO - Pulling for range 76749-102331 using Thread-1
>
> INFO - Download Completed 100.0% for file 607800main_kepler1200_1600-1200.jpg

but what I am expecting is

> INFO - Pulling for range 0-25583 using Thread-1
>
> INFO - Pulling for range 25584-51166 using Thread-2
>
> INFO - Pulling for range 51167-76748 using Thread-3
>
> INFO - Pulling for range 76749-102331 using Thread-4

Please do not mark duplicate, without understanding...
please recommend if there is a better approach of doing what I am trying to do..

Cheers:/

Comment: The number of threads seem to depend on the number of URLs given at command line. So first make sure there actually _are_ multiple threads running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the download happen simultaneously and just writing to the file to be atomic then don't put the `lock` around *downloading* and writing to the file, but just around the write part.

As every thread uses its own file object to write I don't see the need to lock that access anyway.  What you have to make sure is every thread writes to the correct offset, so you need a `seek()` call on the file before writing the data chunk.  Otherwise you'll have to write the chunks in file order, which would make things more complicated.

Comment: Hi @BlackHack I have update the code, however the image is now coming corrupted. I think the order needs to be inlace which seems to be part of the problem

Comment: @san: As said, if the chunks finish out of order you'll have to make sure they are written at the correct position. Open the file in a mode which doesn't first truncate the file to zero bytes length, i.e. _not_ `'wb'` and seek to the position the chunk should go before writing it.